# Apple pay EMV transaction

Tags: applepay, emv, mastercard

I am trying to perform Apple pay transaction. The card edded to apple pay wallet is MasterCard. If I perform a contactless transaction using a physical card, my code works. But when I try to do the same with ApplePay, I get SW 6700 (wrong length) status after the GENERATE AC command.
Here you can see how I construct data for GAC request:

```
9f02 06 000000000100 Amount, Authorised (Numeric)
9f03 06 000000000000 Amount, Other (Numeric)
9f1a 02 0804 Terminal Country Code
95 05 0000000000  Terminal Verification Results
5f2a 02 0980 Transaction Currency Code
9a 03  210511 Transaction Date
9c 01 00 Transaction Type
9f37 04 3357A30A Unpredictable Number
9f35 01 21 Terminal Type
9f45 02 0000 Data Authentication Code
9f4c 08 0000000000000000 ICC Dynamic Number
9f34 03  1F0302 Cardholder Verification Method (CVM) Results
9f21 03  131340 Transaction Time HHMMSS
9f7c 14(20 dec) 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 Customer Exclusive Data (CED)
```

So, my final data is:

```
80 AE 8000 42 000000000030 000000000000 0804 0000008001 0980 210511 00 3357A30A 21 0000 0000000000000000 1F0302 133040 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 00
```

Le byte is 42 (66 dec) and it is correct if physical card is used.
What is wrong with Apple Pay?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that CDOL1 differs when using ApplePay with the same card.
Thus tag 0x8C (CDOL1) using ApplePay is:

```
9f02069f03069f1a0295055f2a029a039c019f37049f35019f45029f4c089f34039f1d089f15029f4e14
```

And using physical contactless card (MasterCard):

```
9f02069f03069f1a0295055f2a029a039c019f37049f35019f45029f4c089f34039f21039f7c14
```

So, they are not equal, and deconstruction gives us such a data items:

```
9f02 06 000000000100 
9f03 06 000000000000
9f1a 02 0804
95 05 0000000000
5f2a 02  0980
9a 03 210511
9c 01 00
9f37 04  3357A30A
9f35 01  21
9f45 02 0000
9f4c 08 0000000000000000
9f34 03 1F0302
9f1d 08 6CF8000000000000
9f15 02 0000
9f4e 14 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

So, the final data for GENERATE AC command should be:

```
80 AE 8000 49 000000000030 000000000000 0804 0000008001 0980 210511 00 3357A30A 21 0000 0000000000000000 1F0302 6CF8000000000000 0000 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 00
```

Le = 73 dec / 0x49 hex.
This works fine.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. Why aren't you performing all the steps of the transaction and using the data you receive in it?